# displaying only contacts from account

Tags: apex, query

I need to display only the contacts from the particular account. If I give the contact Id in the get statement I should display only the contacts of the respective account.

Here is my code:

```
List<Account>Acl = new List<Account>([Select Id,name from Account limit 10 ]);
Map <Id,Account> mpn = new map<Id,Account>();
for (Account a : acl)
{
    mpn.put(a.Id,a);
}
system.debug(mpn.get('0019000000PDZvkAAH'));
```

and I should not call the contact through dot operator i.e. (mpn.get('0019000000PDZvkAAH').contacts)

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood your question, but what I think you're trying to do is get all the contacts of a particular account through a `get` on a map?

You don't need to manually fill a map in Apex, and you can also directly query contacts from account.

```
Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account]); // Will create a Map with AccountId as Key and the account as value
Id accountId; // fill in the accountId you wish to query for contacts
if(accountId != null && accountsMap.containsKey(accountId))
{
    System.debug(accountsMap.get(accountId).contacts); // Will return a List of Contacts
}
else
{
    System.debug('No Records Found');
}
```

**A better way**

Query contacts directly, and filter only the ones needed, this will result in significant faster processing times when having alot of accounts/contacts, because in your case, you query them all

```
Id accountId; // Fill in the accountId you want
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]);
System.debug(contacts);
```